# Using the jQuery Framework to apply css class to found match on keyup in an input box/ul list

Tags: jquery, javascript

I need your help.

I am not sure what the technology is called for this, but you know how in some websites you start typing some value in an input box and the nearest result becomes immediately highlighted.

I assume that it captures this info on some sort of a key up event. I'd like to have the same concept applied to my example,

so that if for example I type in the value `'698'`in my input box, jQuery would find, select and apply my css class titled:`.selected` to the value (same as if I were to click and select it. I think this addon would be neat and purposeful to both the user and the eye.

I guess further to say that, once the css class applied, the function should also move the scroll position to the detected value.

Here's a quick pic of the desired result:

[image]

Much thanks and appreciation for everyones help & support in advance,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#refdocs {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
#refdocs_main {
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 179px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
#refdocs_input{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    height: 20px;

}
#refdocs_wrapper{
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#refdocs_list {
    width: 100%;
}
#refdocs_list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#refdocs_list li {
    cursor: default;
    padding: 2px;
}
.selected {
    background: rgb(228,228,228);
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

    $('#refdocs_list ul li').click(function () {
        $('#refdocs_list ul li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        document.getElementById('refdocs').value = $(this).text()
    });




}
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="refdocs_main">

        <div id="refdocs_input"><input type="text" id="refdocs"></div>

        <div id="refdocs_wrapper">

            <div id="refdocs_list">
                <ul>
                    <li>9094203</li>
                    <li>9279863</li>
                    <li>9023698</li>
                    <li>8993127</li>
                    <li>9037891</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check out [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#basics) it is built to do exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look like this

```
$("#refdocs").keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                var va = $( this ).val();
                $("li:contains(" + va + ")").first().css("text-decoration","underline");

            });
```